# NextJS - How to convert this approach to NextJS pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-router-dom

I'm new to learning NextJS. I'm moving my old project to NextJS. I was using `react-router-dom` and I'm wondering how to do the following approach in NextJS Pages?

```js
<Route path={['/','/search/:search?','/top_sold','/recent_added',]} exact component={Home} />
<Route path='/faq/:section?' component={FAQ}  />
<Route path={['/client/:username?/:type?/:search?']} component={Profile} />
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next.Js uses a file-system based router built on the concept of pages.

**Index routes**

The router will automatically route files named index to the root of the directory.

```
pages/index.js → /
pages/blog/index.js → /blog
```

**Nested routes**

The router supports nested files. If you create a nested folder structure, files will automatically be routed in the same way still.

```
pages/blog/first-post.js → /blog/first-post
pages/dashboard/settings/username.js → /dashboard/settings/username
```

**Dynamic route segments**

To match a dynamic segment, you can use the bracket syntax. This allows you to match named parameters.

```
pages/blog/[slug].js → /blog/:slug (/blog/hello-world)
pages/[username]/settings.js → /:username/settings (/foo/settings)
pages/post/[...all].js → /post/* (/post/2020/id/title)
```

Find out more from [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction)

Answer (score 0):

With Next.js, you can express the same application structure in the file system. When a file is added to the pages directory it's automatically available as a route.
Eg: `<Route path='/faq/:section?' component={FAQ}  />` can be converted in Next.js as file in location `pages/faq/[[...section]].js` having component FAQ

For more details

https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-react-router

Answer (score 0):

In NextJs, it is only expected to put your file inside the *pages* directory. No other external libraries are needed. If your routes are dynamic use *[dynamicRoute].js* file naming inside the *pages* folder. Have a look at the following snippet:

```
pages/blog/first-post.js → /blog/first-post
pages/dashboard/settings/username.js → /dashboard/settings/username
pages/blog/[slug].js → /blog/:slug (/blog/hello-world)
pages/[username]/settings.js → /:username/settings (/foo/settings)
pages/post/[...all].js → /post/* (/post/2020/id/title)
```

for more information read their official [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction)